# Heroku: Cannot find package 'mongodb'

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, heroku, mongodb-atlas

Im trying to upload my project to heroku, but my app keeps crashing on
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'mongodb'.

The project is angular and Node.js with express
I followed some guides and inserted the mongo URI path to the environment in heroku.
it seems I might missed something..

my package.json in server library:

```
{
  "name": "src",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "mongodb": "^4.6.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.14.0",
    "npm": "8.5.2"
  }
}
```

The error on heroku:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nUHP.png)

The app.js:

```
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'
import bearerToken from "express-bearer-token"
import path from 'path';
import {fileURLToPath} from 'url';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

import { loginRoutes } from './routes/login.routes.js'
import { taskRoutes } from './routes/task.routes.js'
import { usersRoutes } from './routes/users.routes.js'
import { authorize } from './controllers/authorize.controller.js'

dotenv.config()

export const envValue = process.env

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const app = express()

const client = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGODB_URI)
await client.connect()
export const usersDB = await client.db('Users').collection('users')
export const tasksDB = await client.db('Tasks').collection('tasks')

app.use(cors())
// Serve only the static files form the dist directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/taski-web-app'));

app.get('/*', function(req,res) {
    
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/dist/taski-web-app/index.html'));
});


app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use('/', loginRoutes)

app.use(bearerToken())

app.use('/', authorize)

app.use('/', taskRoutes)

app.use('/', usersRoutes)

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 1000, '0.0.0.0', function(){
    console.log("server is listening on port 1000")
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: "my package.json in server library"—Heroku only cares about the `package.json` in your _root_ directory. If that file doesn't somehow trigger a build in your server directory the file you show above will be ignored. Please [edit] and show your main `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Not ignoring the `node_modules` folder when pushing to Heroku master seems to have been the problem.

Removing the `node_modules` folder and then pushing to master did the trick.